# Searchable tuple with a yes/no loop function added - Python

Tags: python

So this is what i've got, but the issue seems to be that the yesno variable is not being defined even after the user enters a correct value?

```
tuple = (#tuple containing list we want to search#)

for i in tuple:
    print(i,end=' ')
    
def main():
    Enter_Name = str(input('Enter Search:'))
    if Enter_Name in tuple:
        print('Yes its in there')
    elif Enter_Name not in tuple:
        print('No  its not there')

main()

def yes_or_no():
    yesno = str(input("Would You Like to Search Again?")).lower
    yesChoice = ['yes', 'y']
    noChoice = ['no', 'n']
    if yesno in yesChoice:
        main()
    elif yesno in noChoice:
        print("Goodbye")
    else:
        print("Please Enter either yes or no")
        yes_or_no()
    
yes_or_no()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You need parentheses `()` after `.lower`: `.lower()`. Just FYI, adding `#` at the end of a comment does not end the comment (maybe you were thinking of `/*` in C?). Python comments continue until the end of the line.

Comment: `tuple` is a built-in function in Python which you are overwriting. Use a different, more descriptive variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding parentheses to the call to .lower()
It's a method, so you have to use the parentheses to actually call it. Right now yesno is just a reference to the method and not the value after it is evaluated.